# htaccess re-write for subfolders?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction with what I'm trying to do.
I'm trying to re-write so that all subfolders will re-direct to one folder while keeping the first subfolder info, along with the rest of the URL.

Example:

http://www.example.com/**billy**/profile/info.php

http://www.example.com/**mike**/profile/info.php

http://www.example.com/**sarah**/profile/info.php

http://www.example.com/**mark**/profile/info.php

where it would redirect to:

http://www.example.com/home/profile/info.php?user_name=$1
where I can get the user name and redirect to the correct page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(?!home/)([^/]+)/(profile/info\.php)$ home/$2?user_name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank-you my friend!  This put me on the right track!!  Thank-you so much for your assistance.

Comment: This is almost working, but what I need is to be able to get anything after the first subfolder (the username):

http://www.example.com/mark/profile/images/img.jpg

http://www,example.com/mark/music/folder/index.php

http://www.example.com/mark/homework/index.php


where anything after the first folder would just redirect to:

http://www.example.com/home/(full url from above)

Comment: Are there only 3 folders to be rewritten after first level i.e. `music, profile & homework` ?

Comment: No, it could be anything.  I guess I'm trying to create subdomains for each user where regardless what is added to the end that it always will just use the same files on the site, just capturing the user name as a variable.

Comment: Try this rule then: `RewriteRule ^(?!home/)([^/]+)/([^/]+/.+)$ home/$2?user_name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` but if it doesn't work I suggest opening a new question. It is not easy to understand a problem from comments.